# Stroustrup's Header error working with FLTK

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, fltk

I have successfully installed FLTK in VS 2015 Community Edition. I am dealing with other headers, part of Stroustrup's book, to build graphs and to create custom windows where to attach them. My problem is that when I am trying to compile I receive 4 error messagges (plus 23 Warnings):

> (active)      IntelliSense    namespace "std" has no member
> "Vector"  Win32Project1   c:\Users\Leonardo\Documents\Visual Studio
> 2015\Projects\Win32Project1\Win32Project1\Window.h    17
>
> Error C2873   Build   'Vector': symbol cannot be used in a
> using-declaration Win32Project1   c:\users\leonardo\documents\visual
> studio 2015\projects\win32project1\win32project1\Window.h 17
>
> Error C2039   Build   'Vector': is not a member of
> 'std' Win32Project1   c:\users\leonardo\documents\visual studio
> 2015\projects\win32project1\win32project1\Window.h    17
>
> Error C2440   Build   'return': cannot convert from 'std::ifstream' to
> 'bool'    Win32Project1   C:\Users\Leonardo\Documents\Visual Studio
> 2015\Projects\Win32Project1\Win32Project1\Graph.cpp   371

I have set a Win32Project (not a Console Project), following the steps of this site: http://www.c-jump.com/bcc/common/Talk2/Cxx/FltkInstallVC/FltkInstallVC.html.
If I run the test example it perfectly works so, I guess, to have correctly installed the additional library.

Furthermore, I have added every header or source file provided by the author in the project.

main.cpp:

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"
#include "Graph.h"
#include "Simple_window.h"


int main()
{
    using namespace Graph_lib;

    Point tl{ 100,100 };

    Simple_window win{ tl,600,400,"My Window" };

    win.wait_for_button();

}
```

All headers and source file can be reached at: http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/Programming-code.zip

Here Windows.h

```
//
// This is a GUI support code to the chapters 12-16 of the book
// "Programming -- Principles and Practice Using C++" by Bjarne Stroustrup
//

#ifndef WINDOW_GUARD
#define WINDOW_GUARD

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <FL/Fl.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Window.H>
#include "Point.h"

using std::string;
using std::vector;

namespace Graph_lib
{
    class Shape;   // "forward declare" Shape
    class Widget;

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    class Window : public Fl_Window { 
    public:
        // let the system pick the location:
        Window(int w, int h, const string& title);
        // top left corner in xy
        Window(Point xy, int w, int h, const string& title);    

        virtual ~Window() { }

        int x_max() const { return w; }
        int y_max() const { return h; }

        void resize(int ww, int hh) { w=ww, h=hh; size(ww,hh); }

        void set_label(const string& s) { copy_label(s.c_str()); }

        void attach(Shape& s) { shapes.push_back(&s); }
        void attach(Widget&);

        void detach(Shape& s);     // remove s from shapes 
        void detach(Widget& w);    // remove w from window (deactivates callbacks)

        void put_on_top(Shape& p); // put p on top of other shapes

    protected:
        void draw();

    private:
        vector<Shape*> shapes;     // shapes attached to window
        int w,h;                   // window size

        void init();
    };
```

and Graph.cpp

```
//
// This is a GUI support code to the chapters 12-16 of the book
// "Programming -- Principles and Practice Using C++" by Bjarne Stroustrup
//

#include <FL/Fl_GIF_Image.H>
#include <FL/Fl_JPEG_Image.H>
#include "Graph.h"

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace Graph_lib {

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Shape::Shape() : 
    lcolor(fl_color()),      // default color for lines and characters
    ls(0),                   // default style
    fcolor(Color::invisible) // no fill
{}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

void Shape::add(Point p)     // protected
{
    points.push_back(p);
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

void Shape::set_point(int i,Point p)        // not used; not necessary so far
{
    points[i] = p;
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

void Shape::draw_lines() const
{
    if (color().visibility() && 1<points.size())    // draw sole pixel?
        for (unsigned int i=1; i<points.size(); ++i)
            fl_line(points[i-1].x,points[i-1].y,points[i].x,points[i].y);
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

void Shape::draw() const
{
    Fl_Color oldc = fl_color();
    // there is no good portable way of retrieving the current style
    fl_color(lcolor.as_int());            // set color
    fl_line_style(ls.style(),ls.width()); // set style
    draw_lines();
    fl_color(oldc);      // reset color (to previous)
    fl_line_style(0);    // reset line style to default
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------


void Shape::move(int dx, int dy)    // move the shape +=dx and +=dy
{
    for (int i = 0; i<points.size(); ++i) {
        points[i].x+=dx;
        points[i].y+=dy;
    }
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Line::Line(Point p1, Point p2)    // construct a line from two points
{
    add(p1);    // add p1 to this shape
    add(p2);    // add p2 to this shape
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

void Lines::add(Point p1, Point p2)
{
    Shape::add(p1);
    Shape::add(p2);
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// draw lines connecting pairs of points
void Lines::draw_lines() const
{
    if (color().visibility())
        for (int i=1; i<number_of_points(); i+=2)
            fl_line(point(i-1).x,point(i-1).y,point(i).x,point(i).y);
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// does two lines (p1,p2) and (p3,p4) intersect?
// if se return the distance of the intersect point as distances from p1
inline pair<double,double> line_intersect(Point p1, Point p2, Point p3, Point p4, bool& parallel) 
{
    double x1 = p1.x;
    double x2 = p2.x;
    double x3 = p3.x;
    double x4 = p4.x;
    double y1 = p1.y;
    double y2 = p2.y;
    double y3 = p3.y;
    double y4 = p4.y;

    double denom = ((y4 - y3)*(x2-x1) - (x4-x3)*(y2-y1));
    if (denom == 0){
        parallel= true;
        return pair<double,double>(0,0);
    }
    parallel = false;
    return pair<double,double>( ((x4-x3)*(y1-y3) - (y4-y3)*(x1-x3))/denom,
                                ((x2-x1)*(y1-y3) - (y2-y1)*(x1-x3))/denom);
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//intersection between two line segments
//Returns true if the two segments intersect,
//in which case intersection is set to the point of intersection
bool line_segment_intersect(Point p1, Point p2, Point p3, Point p4, Point& intersection){
   bool parallel;
   pair<double,double> u = line_intersect(p1,p2,p3,p4,parallel);
   if (parallel || u.first < 0 || u.first > 1 || u.second < 0 || u.second > 1) return false;
   intersection.x = p1.x + u.first*(p2.x - p1.x);
   intersection.y = p1.y + u.first*(p2.y - p1.y);
   return true;
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

void Polygon::add(Point p)
{
    int np = number_of_points();

    if (1<np) {    // check that thenew line isn't parallel to the previous one
        if (p==point(np-1)) error("polygon point equal to previous point");
        bool parallel;
        line_intersect(point(np-1),p,point(np-2),point(np-1),parallel);
        if (parallel)
            error("two polygon points lie in a straight line");
    }

    for (int i = 1; i<np-1; ++i) {    // check that new segment doesn't interset and old point
        Point ignore(0,0);
        if (line_segment_intersect(point(np-1),p,point(i-1),point(i),ignore))
            error("intersect in polygon");
    }
    

    Closed_polyline::add(p);
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

void Polygon::draw_lines() const
{
    if (number_of_points() < 3) error("less than 3 points in a Polygon");
    Closed_polyline::draw_lines();
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

void Open_polyline::draw_lines() const
{
    if (fill_color().visibility()) {
        fl_color(fill_color().as_int());
        fl_begin_complex_polygon();
        for(int i=0; i<number_of_points(); ++i){
            fl_vertex(point(i).x, point(i).y);
        }
        fl_end_complex_polygon();
        fl_color(color().as_int());    // reset color
    }
    
    if (color().visibility())
        Shape::draw_lines();
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

void Closed_polyline::draw_lines() const
{
    Open_polyline::draw_lines();    // first draw the "open poly line part"
    // then draw closing line:
    if (color().visibility())
        fl_line(point(number_of_points()-1).x, 
        point(number_of_points()-1).y,
        point(0).x,
        point(0).y);
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

void draw_mark(Point xy, char c)
{
    static const int dx = 4;
    static const int dy = 4;

    string m(1,c);
    fl_draw(m.c_str(),xy.x-dx,xy.y+dy);
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

void Marked_polyline::draw_lines() const
{
    Open_polyline::draw_lines();
    for (int i=0; i<number_of_points(); ++i) 
        draw_mark(point(i),mark[i%mark.size()]);
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

void Rectangle::draw_lines() const
{
    if (fill_color().visibility()) {    // fill
        fl_color(fill_color().as_int());
        fl_rectf(point(0).x,point(0).y,w,h);
    }

    if (color().visibility()) {    // lines on top of fill
        fl_color(color().as_int());
        fl_rect(point(0).x,point(0).y,w,h);
    }
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Circle::Circle(Point p, int rr)    // center and radius
:r(rr)
{
    add(Point(p.x-r,p.y-r));       // store top-left corner
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Point Circle::center() const
{
    return Point(point(0).x+r, point(0).y+r);
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

void Circle::draw_lines() const
{
    if (color().visibility())
        fl_arc(point(0).x,point(0).y,r+r,r+r,0,360);
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

void Ellipse::draw_lines() const
{
    if (color().visibility())
        fl_arc(point(0).x,point(0).y,w+w,h+h,0,360);
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

void Text::draw_lines() const
{
    int ofnt = fl_font();
    int osz = fl_size();
    fl_font(fnt.as_int(),fnt_sz);
    fl_draw(lab.c_str(),point(0).x,point(0).y);
    fl_font(ofnt,osz);
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Axis::Axis(Orientation d, Point xy, int length, int n, string lab) :
    label(Point(0,0),lab)
{
    if (length<0) error("bad axis length");
    switch (d){
    case Axis::x:
    {
        Shape::add(xy); // axis line
        Shape::add(Point(xy.x+length,xy.y));

        if (1<n) {      // add notches
            int dist = length/n;
            int x = xy.x+dist;
            for (int i = 0; i<n; ++i) {
                notches.add(Point(x,xy.y),Point(x,xy.y-5));
                x += dist;
            }
        }
        // label under the line
        label.move(length/3,xy.y+20);
        break;
    }
    case Axis::y:
    {
        Shape::add(xy); // a y-axis goes up
        Shape::add(Point(xy.x,xy.y-length));

        if (1<n) {      // add notches
            int dist = length/n;
            int y = xy.y-dist;
            for (int i = 0; i<n; ++i) {
                notches.add(Point(xy.x,y),Point(xy.x+5,y));
                y -= dist;
            }
        }
        // label at top
        label.move(xy.x-10,xy.y-length-10);
        break;
    }
    case Axis::z:
        error("z axis not implemented");
    }
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

void Axis::draw_lines() const
{
    Shape::draw_lines();
    notches.draw();  // the notches may have a different color from the line
    label.draw();    // the label may have a different color from the line
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

void Axis::set_color(Color c)
{
    Shape::set_color(c);
    notches.set_color(c);
    label.set_color(c);
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

void Axis::move(int dx, int dy)
{
    Shape::move(dx,dy);
    notches.move(dx,dy);
    label.move(dx,dy);
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Function::Function(Fct f, double r1, double r2, Point xy,
                   int count, double xscale, double yscale)
// graph f(x) for x in [r1:r2) using count line segments with (0,0) displayed at xy
// x coordinates are scaled by xscale and y coordinates scaled by yscale
{
    if (r2-r1<=0) error("bad graphing range");
    if (count <=0) error("non-positive graphing count");
    double dist = (r2-r1)/count;
    double r = r1;
    for (int i = 0; i<count; ++i) {
        add(Point(xy.x+int(r*xscale),xy.y-int(f(r)*yscale)));
        r += dist;
    }
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

bool can_open(const string& s)
// check if a file named s exists and can be opened for reading
{
    ifstream ff(s.c_str());
    return ff;
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#define ARRAY_SIZE(a) (sizeof(a)/sizeof((a)[0]))

Suffix::Encoding get_encoding(const string& s)
{
    struct SuffixMap 
    { 
        const char*      extension;
        Suffix::Encoding suffix;
    };

    static SuffixMap smap[] = {
        {".jpg",  Suffix::jpg},
        {".jpeg", Suffix::jpg},
        {".gif",  Suffix::gif},
    };

    for (int i = 0, n = ARRAY_SIZE(smap); i < n; i++)
    {
        int len = strlen(smap[i].extension);

        if (s.length() >= len && s.substr(s.length()-len, len) == smap[i].extension)
            return smap[i].suffix;
    }

    return Suffix::none;
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// somewhat over-elaborate constructor
// because errors related to image files can be such a pain to debug
Image::Image(Point xy, string s, Suffix::Encoding e)
    :w(0), h(0), fn(xy,"")
{
    add(xy);

    if (!can_open(s)) {    // can we open s?
        fn.set_label("cannot open \""+s+'\"');
        p = new Bad_image(30,20);    // the "error image"
        return;
    }

    if (e == Suffix::none) e = get_encoding(s);

    switch(e) {        // check if it is a known encoding
    case Suffix::jpg:
        p = new Fl_JPEG_Image(s.c_str());
        break;
    case Suffix::gif:
        p = new Fl_GIF_Image(s.c_str());
        break;
    default:    // Unsupported image encoding
        fn.set_label("unsupported file type \""+s+'\"');
        p = new Bad_image(30,20);    // the "error image"
    }
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

void Image::draw_lines() const
{
    if (fn.label()!="") fn.draw_lines();

    if (w&&h)
        p->draw(point(0).x,point(0).y,w,h,cx,cy);
    else
        p->draw(point(0).x,point(0).y);
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

} // of namespace Graph_lib
```

I hope someone could help me.

**EDIT**

```
    /*
std_lib_facilities.h
*/

/*
    simple "Programming: Principles and Practice using C++ (second edition)" course header to
    be used for the first few weeks.
    It provides the most common standard headers (in the global namespace)
    and minimal exception/error support.

    Students: please don't try to understand the details of headers just yet.
    All will be explained. This header is primarily used so that you don't have
    to understand every concept all at once.

    By Chapter 10, you don't need this file and after Chapter 21, you'll understand it

    Revised April 25, 2010: simple_error() added
    
    Revised November 25 2013: remove support for pre-C++11 compilers, use C++11: <chrono>
    Revised November 28 2013: add a few container algorithms
    Revised June 8 2014: added #ifndef to workaround Microsoft C++11 weakness
*/

#ifndef H112
#define H112 251113L


#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<fstream>
#include<sstream>
#include<cmath>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<string>
#include<list>
#include <forward_list>
#include<vector>
#include<unordered_map>
#include<algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <regex>
#include<random>
#include<stdexcept>

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------


//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

typedef long Unicode;

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

using namespace std;

template<class T> string to_string(const T& t)
{
    ostringstream os;
    os << t;
    return os.str();
}

struct Range_error : out_of_range { // enhanced vector range error reporting
    int index;
    Range_error(int i) :out_of_range("Range error: "+to_string(i)), index(i) { }
};


// trivially range-checked vector (no iterator checking):
template< class T> struct Vector : public std::vector<T> {
    using size_type = typename std::vector<T>::size_type;

#ifdef _MSC_VER
    // microsoft doesn't yet support C++11 inheriting constructors
    Vector() { }
    explicit Vector(size_type n) :std::vector<T>(n) {}
    Vector(size_type n, const T& v) :std::vector<T>(n,v) {}
    template <class I>
    Vector(I first, I last) : std::vector<T>(first, last) {}
    Vector(initializer_list<T> list) : std::vector<T>(list) {}
#else
    using std::vector<T>::vector;   // inheriting constructor
#endif

    T& operator[](unsigned int i) // rather than return at(i);
    {
        if (i<0||this->size()<=i) throw Range_error(i);
        return std::vector<T>::operator[](i);
    }
    const T& operator[](unsigned int i) const
    {
        if (i<0||this->size()<=i) throw Range_error(i);
        return std::vector<T>::operator[](i);
    }
};

// disgusting macro hack to get a range checked vector:
#define vector Vector

// trivially range-checked string (no iterator checking):
struct String : std::string {
    using size_type = std::string::size_type;
//  using string::string;

    char& operator[](unsigned int i) // rather than return at(i);
    {
        if (i<0||size()<=i) throw Range_error(i);
        return std::string::operator[](i);
    }

    const char& operator[](unsigned int i) const
    {
        if (i<0||size()<=i) throw Range_error(i);
        return std::string::operator[](i);
    }
};


namespace std {

    template<> struct hash<String>
    {
        size_t operator()(const String& s) const
        {
            return hash<std::string>()(s);
        }
    };

} // of namespace std


struct Exit : runtime_error {
    Exit(): runtime_error("Exit") {}
};

// error() simply disguises throws:
inline void error(const string& s)
{
    throw runtime_error(s);
}

inline void error(const string& s, const string& s2)
{
    error(s+s2);
}

inline void error(const string& s, int i)
{
    ostringstream os;
    os << s <<": " << i;
    error(os.str());
}


template<class T> char* as_bytes(T& i)  // needed for binary I/O
{
    void* addr = &i;    // get the address of the first byte
                        // of memory used to store the object
    return static_cast<char*>(addr); // treat that memory as bytes
}


inline void keep_window_open()
{
    cin.clear();
    cout << "Please enter a character to exit\n";
    char ch;
    cin >> ch;
    return;
}

inline void keep_window_open(string s)
{
    if (s=="") return;
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(120,'\n');
    for (;;) {
        cout << "Please enter " << s << " to exit\n";
        string ss;
        while (cin >> ss && ss!=s)
            cout << "Please enter " << s << " to exit\n";
        return;
    }
}



// error function to be used (only) until error() is introduced in Chapter 5:
inline void simple_error(string s)  // write ``error: s and exit program
{
    cerr << "error: " << s << '\n';
    keep_window_open();     // for some Windows environments
    exit(1);
}

// make std::min() and std::max() accessible on systems with antisocial macros:
#undef min
#undef max


// run-time checked narrowing cast (type conversion). See ???.
template<class R, class A> R narrow_cast(const A& a)
{
    R r = R(a);
    if (A(r)!=a) error(string("info loss"));
    return r;
}

// random number generators. See 24.7.



inline int randint(int min, int max) { static default_random_engine ran; return uniform_int_distribution<>{min, max}(ran); }

inline int randint(int max) { return randint(0, max); }

//inline double sqrt(int x) { return sqrt(double(x)); } // to match C++0x

// container algorithms. See 21.9.

template<typename C>
using Value_type = typename C::value_type;

template<typename C>
using Iterator = typename C::iterator;

template<typename C>
    // requires Container<C>()
void sort(C& c)
{
    std::sort(c.begin(), c.end());
}

template<typename C, typename Pred>
// requires Container<C>() && Binary_Predicate<Value_type<C>>()
void sort(C& c, Pred p)
{
    std::sort(c.begin(), c.end(), p);
}

template<typename C, typename Val>
    // requires Container<C>() && Equality_comparable<C,Val>()
Iterator<C> find(C& c, Val v)
{
    return std::find(c.begin(), c.end(), v);
}

template<typename C, typename Pred>
// requires Container<C>() && Predicate<Pred,Value_type<C>>()
Iterator<C> find_if(C& c, Pred p)
{
    return std::find_if(c.begin(), c.end(), p);
}

#endif //H112
```

Comment: Note that your error messages refer to `Vector` with an upper case "V" whereas the `<vector>` header file declares the type `std::vector` with a lower case "v".  Looking at the Windows.h code in your post I don't see any use of upper case v `Vector`.  Are you sure the code you are compiling matches the code you posted?

Comment: @FrankBoyne Yep I only copy and pasted it here.. I written main on my own and I have just included other headers in the project! There are other 3 headers and I am going to post them.. I really cannot understand what is wrong!

Comment: In Visual Studio type CTRL+Shift+F to bring up the Find in Files dialog.  Type **Vector** in the Find What box, set Look in to "Entire Solution" and check the "Match Case and "Match whole word" boxes under "Find options".  Now click on Find All.  If there's any use of the identifier "Vector" in your solution, that should find it.

Comment: Here what I got:
  C:\Users\Leonardo\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Win32Project1\Win32Project1\std_lib_facilities.h(70):template< class T> struct Vector : public std::vector<T> {
  C:\Users\Leonardo\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Win32Project1\Win32Project1\std_lib_facilities.h(75): Vector() { }
  C:\Users\Leonardo\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Win32Project1\Win32Project1\std_lib_facilities.h(76): explicit Vector(size_type n) :std::vector<T>(n) {}

Comment: C:\Users\Leonardo\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Win32Project1\Win32Project1\std_lib_facilities.h(77): Vector(size_type n, const T& v) :std::vector<T>(n,v) {}
  C:\Users\Leonardo\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Win32Project1\Win32Project1\std_lib_facilities.h(79): Vector(I first, I last) : std::vector<T>(first, last) {}
  C:\Users\Leonardo\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Win32Project1\Win32Project1\std_lib_facilities.h(80): Vector(initializer_list<T> list) : std::vector<T>(list) {}

Comment: C:\Users\Leonardo\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Win32Project1\Win32Project1\std_lib_facilities.h(98):#define vector Vector

Comment: That's strange because the `std_lib_facilities.h` alone works!

Comment: Thanks to another user commenting `std_lib_facilities.h` `#define vector Vector` -> `// #define vector Vector` the 3 errors about Vector conflicts are gone! There is still last left about a function in Graph.cpp

Comment: Your problem is probably being caused by std_lib_facilities.h line 98: `#define vector Vector`.  It tells the preprocessor to substitute `Vector` for `vector` everywhere in your code.  So at line 17 in Windows.h `using std::vector;` gets translated into `using std::Vector;` and the std namespace doesn't define a `Vector`.  You might be able to avoid the problem by deleting the `#include "std_lib_facilities.h"` line from your main.cpp or by moving that include statement down after the other two

Comment: @FrankBoyne Bull's eye! It is so.. You are right! I got only one error lasting.. It refers to a function in  `Graph.cpp ` that should return a  `bool ` while it is returning an  `ifstream ` object

Comment: Solved with `return bool(ff);` Thank you @FrankBoyne! You were very kind!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Error C2440 Build 'return': cannot convert from 'std::ifstream' to 'bool' Win32Project1 C:\Users\Leonardo\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Win32Project1\Win32Project1\Graph.cpp 371

I suspect you're running into a breaking change introduced by C++11.  The code appears to be this:

```
bool can_open(const string& s)
// check if a file named s exists and can be opened for reading
{
    ifstream ff(s.c_str());
    return ff;
}
```

The code used to work by using `operator void *` to cast ff from an `istream` to a `void *` which could then be cast to a `bool`. If the ifstream was bad the cast to `void *` would result in a null pointer which in turn would be treated as `bool` false.

But C++11 introduces an `explicit operator bool()` for streams (and gets rid of the `void *` operator?). Since the `bool` operator is `explicit` the operator won't be used for an implicit cast.

To get `can_open` to compile with the C++11 version of streams you need to make the cast explicit:

```
bool can_open(const string& s)
// check if a file named s exists and can be opened for reading
{
    ifstream ff(s.c_str());
    return (bool)ff;
}
```

However that change will break the code if it is compiled with a pre-C++11 version of streams.